# sqlalchemy gives '/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a python program that uses sqlalchemy. It worked fine, but I just converted to python3, so I'm using all new versions of libraries.. Now I'm getting:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

The link didn't show anything useful...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, TDS doesn't seem to be installed automatically?

```
brew install freeTDS
```

Seems to solve the problem.